# PHP Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, mysql

Hello i have output php error like in title is said so i tried some solutions from some stackoverflow answers from other similar questions by random people but nothing helped so i decide to share my code with all of you maybe someone have solution.
So i have Stripe integration on my website and i used test stripe keys and make success payment after stripe redirect me back my page automatily is programmed to receive success sessions_id to add purcashed credits to user balance and also give message of success so problem is that when i finish payment anything of that not happened and output error in log file is **PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/user123/domain.com/html/account/page.balance.inc.php on line 81**.

Here is my code of 'page.balance.inc.php' file

```
<?php

if (!defined("APP_SIGNATURE")) {

    header("Location: /");
    exit;
}

if (!auth::isSession()) {

    header("Location: /");
    exit;
}

if (auth::getCurrentUserId() == 0) {

    header("Location: /");
    exit;
}

require('html/stripe/init.php');

\Stripe\Stripe::setVerifySslCerts(false);
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $packageId = isset($_POST['packageId']) ? $_POST['packageId'] : 0;

    $result = array(
        "error" => true,
        "error_code" => ERROR_UNKNOWN
    );

    if ($packageId < count($payments_packages)) {

        $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            'line_items' => [[
                'name' => $payments_packages[$packageId]['name'],
                'amount' => $payments_packages[$packageId]['amount'],
                'currency' => 'usd',
                'quantity' => 1,
            ]],
            'payment_intent_data' => [
                'capture_method' => 'automatic',
            ],
            'success_url' => APP_URL.'/account/balance?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
            'cancel_url' => APP_URL.'/account/balance',
        ]);

        $stripeSession = array($session);
        $sessId = ($stripeSession[0]['id']);

        $_SESSION['sessId'] = $sessId;
        $_SESSION['packageId'] = $packageId;

        $result = array(
            "error" => false,
            "error_code" => ERROR_SUCCESS,
            "sessId" => $sessId
        );
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
    exit;
}

$payment = false;

if (isset($_GET['session_id'])) {

    try {

        $response = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::retrieve($_GET['session_id']);

        if (isset($_SESSION['sessId'])) {

            $paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::retrieve($response['payment_intent']);

            if ($paymentIntent['amount_received'] == $response['display_items'][0]['amount'] && $_GET['session_id'] == $_SESSION['sessId']) {

                $account = new account($dbo, auth::getCurrentUserId());
                $account->setBalance($account->getBalance() + $payments_packages[$_SESSION['packageId']]['credits']);

                $payments = new payments($dbo);
                $payments->setRequestFrom(auth::getCurrentUserId());
                $payments->create(PA_BUY_CREDITS, PT_CARD, $payments_packages[$_SESSION['packageId']]['credits'], $payments_packages[$_SESSION['packageId']]['amount']);
                unset($payments);

                unset($_SESSION['sessId']);
                unset($_SESSION['packageId']);

                $fcm = new fcm($dbo);
                $fcm->setRequestFrom(auth::getCurrentUserId());
                $fcm->setRequestTo(auth::getCurrentUserId());
                $fcm->setType(GCM_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ACCOUNT_SETTINGS);
                $fcm->setTitle("You settings is changed.");
                $fcm->prepare();
                $fcm->send();
                unset($fcm);

                $payment = true;
            }
        }

    } catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException $e) {

        $payment = false;
    }
}

$account = new account($dbo, auth::getCurrentUserId());

$page_id = "balance";

$css_files = array("main.css", "my.css");
$page_title = $LANG['page-balance']." | ".APP_TITLE;

include_once("html/common/site_header.inc.php");
```

?>

```
<div class="main-column row">

    <?php

        include_once("html/common/site_sidenav.inc.php");
    ?>

    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12" id="content">

        <div class="main-content">

            <div class="standard-page">

                <h1><?php echo $LANG['page-balance']; ?></h1>

                <div class="tab-container">
                    <nav class="tabs">
                        <a href="/account/settings"><span class="tab"><?php echo $LANG['page-profile-settings']; ?></span></a>
                        <a href="/account/settings/privacy"><span class="tab"><?php echo $LANG['page-privacy-settings']; ?></span></a>
                        <a href="/account/balance"><span class="tab active"><?php echo $LANG['page-balance']; ?></span></a>
                        <a href="/account/settings/services"><span class="tab"><?php echo $LANG['label-services']; ?></span></a>
                        <a href="/account/settings/password"><span class="tab"><?php echo $LANG['label-password']; ?></span></a>
                        <a href="/account/settings/referrals"><span class="tab"><?php echo $LANG['page-referrals']; ?></span></a>
                        <a href="/account/settings/blacklist"><span class="tab"><?php echo $LANG['page-blacklist']; ?></span></a>
                        <a href="/account/settings/deactivation"><span class="tab"><?php echo $LANG['page-deactivate-account']; ?></span></a>
                    </nav>
                </div>

                <?php

                if ($payment) {

                    ?>

                    <div class="success-container" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                        <ul class="m-0">
                            <b><?php echo $LANG['label-thanks']; ?></b>
                            <br>
                            <?php echo $LANG['label-payments-success_added']; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <?php
                }
                ?>

                <header class="top-banner px-0">

                    <div class="info">
                        <h1><?php echo $LANG['page-balance']; ?></h1>
                        <p><?php echo $LANG['page-balance-desc'] ?></p>
                        <p><?php echo $LANG['label-balance']; ?> <b><?php echo $account->getBalance(); ?> <?php echo $LANG['label-credits']; ?></b></p>
                    </div>

                </header>

                <?php

                    if (APP_DEMO) {

                        ?>

                        <div class="warning-container d-block col-12">
                            <p class="m-0">
                                <span><b>For testing:</b></span>
                                <span class="d-block">Use card number for test: 4242424242424242</span>
                                <span class="d-block">CVC and other data: any</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>

                        <?php
                    }
                ?>

                <header class="top-banner p-0">
                    <div class="info">
                        <h1><?php echo $LANG['action-buy-credits']; ?></h1>
                    </div>
                </header>

                <div class="row col-12 px-0">

                <?php

                    foreach ($payments_packages as $package) {

                        ?>
                        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 mt-2 p-0">

                            <a class="stripe-buy-button button blue d-block mx-2" onclick="Payments.new(<?php echo $package['id']; ?>); return false;" href="javascript: void(0)"><i class="icofont icofont-stripe-alt"></i> <?php echo $package['name']." ".$LANG['label-payments-for']." $".$package['amount'] / 100; ?></a>
                        </div>

                        <?php
                    }
                ?>
                </div>

                <header class="top-banner px-0 pb-0">
                    <div class="info">
                        <h1><?php echo $LANG['label-payments-history']; ?></h1>
                    </div>
                </header>

                <div class="listview">
                    <table class="bordered data-tables responsive-table">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr class="listview-header">
                            <th class="text-center"><?php echo $LANG['label-payments-credits']; ?></th>
                            <th class="text-center"><?php echo $LANG['label-payments-amount']; ?></th>
                            <th class="text-right"><?php echo $LANG['label-payments-description']; ?></th>
                            <th class="text-right"><?php echo $LANG['label-payments-date']; ?></th>
                        </tr>

                        <?php

                        $payments = new payments($dbo);
                        $payments->setRequestFrom(auth::getCurrentUserId());

                        $result = $payments->get(0, 30);

                        if (count($result['items']) == 0) {

                            ?>

                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="5" class="text-center">
                                    <div class="card information-banner border-0 shadow-none m-0">
                                        <div class="card-header border-0">
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <h5 class="m-0"><?php echo $LANG['label-empty-list']; ?></h5>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <?php

                        } else {

                            foreach ($result['items'] as $key => $value) {

                                ?>

                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-center">
                                        <?php
                                        switch ($value['paymentAction']) {

                                            case PA_BUY_CREDITS: {

                                                echo "<span class=\"green\">+".$value['credits']."</span>";
                                                break;
                                            }

                                            case PA_BUY_REGISTRATION_BONUS: {

                                                echo "<span class=\"green\">+".$value['credits']."</span>";
                                                break;
                                            }

                                            case PA_BUY_REFERRAL_BONUS: {

                                                echo "<span class=\"green\">+".$value['credits']."</span>";
                                                break;
                                            }

                                            default: {

                                                echo "<span class=\"red\">-".$value['credits']."</span>";
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-center">
                                        <?php
                                        switch ($value['paymentAction']) {

                                            case PA_BUY_CREDITS: {

                                                if ($value['amount'] > 0) {

                                                    echo "$".$value['amount'] / 100;
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                            }

                                            default: {

                                                echo "";
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-right" style="word-break: break-word">
                                        <?php
                                        switch ($value['paymentAction']) {

                                            case PA_BUY_CREDITS: {

                                                switch ($value['paymentType']) {

                                                    case PT_CARD: {

                                                        echo $LANG['label-payments-credits-stripe'];
                                                        break;
                                                    }

                                                    case PT_GOOGLE_PURCHASE: {

                                                        echo $LANG['label-payments-credits-android'];
                                                        break;
                                                    }

                                                    case PT_APPLE_PURCHASE: {

                                                        echo $LANG['label-payments-credits-ios'];
                                                        break;
                                                    }

                                                    case PT_ADMOB_REWARDED_ADS: {

                                                        echo $LANG['label-payments-credits-admob'];
                                                        break;
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                break;
                                            }

                                            case PA_BUY_GIFT: {

                                                echo $LANG['label-payments-send-gift'];
                                                break;
                                            }

                                            case PA_BUY_VERIFIED_BADGE: {

                                                echo $LANG['label-payments-verified-badge'];
                                                break;
                                            }

                                            case PA_BUY_GHOST_MODE: {

                                                echo $LANG['label-payments-ghost-mode'];
                                                break;
                                            }

                                            case PA_BUY_PRO_MODE: {

                                                echo $LANG['label-payments-pro-mode'];
                                                break;
                                            }

                                            case PA_BUY_MESSAGE_PACKAGE: {

                                                echo $LANG['label-payments-message-package'];
                                                break;
                                            }

                                            case PA_BUY_SPOTLIGHT: {

                                                echo $LANG['label-payments-spotlight-feature'];
                                                break;
                                            }

                                            case PA_BUY_DISABLE_ADS: {

                                                echo $LANG['label-payments-off-admob'];
                                                break;
                                            }

                                            case PA_BUY_REGISTRATION_BONUS: {

                                                echo $LANG['label-payments-registration-bonus'];
                                                break;
                                            }

                                            case PA_BUY_REFERRAL_BONUS: {

                                                echo $LANG['label-payments-referral-bonus'];
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><?php echo $value['date']; ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <?php
                            }
                        }

                        ?>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
```

//set your publishable key
    var stripe = Stripe('');

    window.Payments || ( window.Payments = {} );

    Payments.new = function (package_id) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/account/balance',
            data: "packageId=" + package_id,
            dataType: 'json',
            timeout: 30000,
            success: function(response){

                if (response.hasOwnProperty('error')) {

                    if (response.error === false) {

                        if (response.hasOwnProperty('sessId')) {

                            stripe.redirectToCheckout({
                                // Make the id field from the Checkout Session creation API response
                                // available to this file, so you can provide it as parameter here
                                // instead of the {{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}} placeholder.
                                sessionId: response.sessId
                            }).then(function (result) {
                                // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
                                // error, display the localized error message to your customer
                                // using `result.error.message`.
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, type){


            }
        });
    };

    $('.btn-stripe').click(function() {

        Payments.new(1);
    });

Comment: Either `$paymentIntent` or `$response['display_items'][0]` is null. You'll need to figure out why.

Comment: Yes i find it , that code needed to be replaced with this 
`code`  `($paymentIntent['amount_received'] == $response['amount_total'] && $_GET['session_id'] == $_SESSION['sessId']) { `  `code`